# Activeandroid how to select column, Like select name from student

Tags: sqlite, activeandroid

i have `Select().from(student.class).execute();`

changing it to `Select("name").from(student.class).execute();` is not working and giving error

and also if if get a List of rows from select query how to read column by column from that list

```
 public static List student() {

    return new Select().from(student.class).execute();
}
```

How can i iterate in the returned list by column wise : say id,name,roll etc

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got the solution :D

```
 List<Students> StudentList = new Select(new String[]{"Id,sers_id,name"}).from(Students.class).execute();
    return StudentList ;
```

and by accessing list bojects i can access the values

```
 List mList = Students .allStudents();
 Students sm = (Students) mList.get(0);

   Log.e("number of semester",":"+sm.name);
```